# Saving data with DynamicField Controls and other ASP.NET controls?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I had a bunch of asp.net DynamicFields which took care of saving data for me?  I had to switch one of the DynamicFields to a DropDownList and now it does not save the selected value?  Do I have to override my save functionality or is there something I can set that will still make it save even thought it is not a DynamicField anymore?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create a custom Field template to house you dropdown list and then set that in the dynamic field using UIHint